# Trying to understand why I am getting a lock timeout exception with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, session

I am updating an object in my business layer with the dao layer looking like

```
String sql = "Update tbl_ExpenseTransaction set Status=:status where ExpenseTransactionID=:tranID";
    getSessionCurrent().createSQLQuery( sql ).setString( "status", status.getIdValue() )
    .setInteger( "tranID", tranId )
    .executeUpdate();
```

After this update, the next business logic is to call another web service, which in turn updates ExpenseTransaction again, at this point I get a lock timeout exception from hibernate telling me to restart transaction. I am wondering if `.executeUpdate()` is not releasing the lock? I googled that sql will lock a row during an update, makes sense, but I would imagine that after that statement gets run that it is unlocked so the next call to update that object will succeed.

I tried closing the current session after the execute update but that immediately failed, and well we use getSessionCurrent everywhere.

Ultimately I just want to be able to update the same object in the same transaction, and avoid this lock timeout.

edit: in case this helps, switching the order of the method calls(the ones that update the object) seems to have fixed the issue.. dont know why yet

Answer (score 0):

No need to close session. Try to begin/commit transaction where the executeUpdate() is called. Looks like your webservice call opens one more transaction to update the same record but the first transaction waits for the webservice call to commit.

So the first opens, updates the records and calls webservice (without commit).

The webservice tries to update the same record but it's locked by the first call which waits fro webservice call result.